# Reading a .csv from S3 bucket with a profile

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have to read a .csv file from a S3 bucket with a profile.

This is what I am doing

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myProfile')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
f1 = 'myFile.csv.gz'
bucket = "myBucket"
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= f1)
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body']) # 'Body' is a key word
```

but I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object'
```

Comment: `get_object` is a call for `s3.client`, not `s3.resource`.

Comment: As @jordanm pointed out, you can change from `session.resource('s3')` to `session.client('s3')` and it would work.